# How to carry the value of checkbox to a php page and output an .xls file?

Tags: php, html, mysql, excel, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to download the contents from mysql db on checkbox selection and button click in excel format. The program is working. But the problem is that I'm only getting one value instead of the entire row. An error on excel file shows undefined index on the line of query.

```
    <form action="connect.php" method="POST">

     <table class= "table table-condensed table-striped">

     <thead>
     <tr class="warning">
     <th></th>
     <th>Delivery No.</th>
     <th>Invoice Number</th>
     <th>Bill Date</th>
     <th>Customer</th>
     <th>Quantity</th>
     <th>Brand</th>

     </tr>

     </thead>

     <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($filter_result)){ ?>
                      <tr>

<td class="border-right" align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="check[]" value= "<?php echo $row['Delivery_no']; ?>" /></td>    
<td><?php echo $row['Delivery_no'];?></td>  
<td><?php echo $row['Invoice_no'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Bill_date'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Bill_to_party'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Quantity'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Brand']; } ?></td>
                        </tr>   



     </table>
     <br>

     <input type= "submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary button-loading">

     </form>
```

***PHP CODE***

```
if (is_array($_REQUEST['check']) and count($_REQUEST['check']) > 0)
{
    $checks = implode(array_map('intval', $_REQUEST['check']));

    $sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName WHERE Delivery_no IN ($checks)" ;
    echo $sql;
    $result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       if(!empty($_POST['check'])) {
          // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
          foreach($_POST['check'] as $selected) {
             echo $selected ;
          }
       }
    }        
    $sep = "\t";     
    for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
       echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
    }
    print("\n");      
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
       $schema_insert = "";
       for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++) {
          if(!isset($row[$j]))
             $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
          elseif ($row[$j] != "")
             $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
          else
             $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
       }
       $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
       $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
       $schema_insert .= "\t";
       print(trim($schema_insert));
       print "\n";
    }  
    $file_ending = "xls";
    header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
    header("Expires: 0");
}
```

Comment: First thing is use mysqli or PDO instead mysql.

Comment: can you please show us how did you fetched `$row['Delivery_no']` from `$result`

Comment: I've updated the code. Please check.

Comment: Do you mean that you need `$row['Invoice_no']` and `$row['Bill_date']` ..... to be sent to the server ? if this is the case then you have to put there values as `<input>` elements ! the browser sends only `<input>` element , he is not sending table or `<td>` values

Comment: so i just have to put <input> instead of <td>? but then how would I create a table without using table elements?

Comment: put `<input>` inside `<td>` the browser will send every `<input>` element inside the `<form>` element if it is not `disabled`

Comment: example `<td><input name='age' value ='30'></td>` and you will find that on the php script inside `$_POST['age']` or `$_GET['age']` depending on your request method

Comment: and should I do the same with <th> too?

Comment: if you need the data inside `<th>` element to be sent to the PHP script ,then put them in `<input>` elements too

Comment: so, <td><input name='Invoice_no' value='invoice'>  INSTEAD OF  <td><?php echo $row['Invoice_no'];?></td>  ???

Comment: `<td><input name='Invoice_no' value="<?php echo$row['Invoice_no']?>"</td>`  this line will send to the PHP script a parameter with the name "Invoice_no" and a value of *what is inside `$row['Invoice_no']`* . you will find this value inside your PHP code in the variable `$_POST['Invoice_no']`. what exactly do you need to send to the server -*php code*-?

Comment: there a total 21 columns in the database. I've just displayed the important ones on the form.. but on button click the entire checked row selected on checkbox should be retrieved with the 21 columns. I hope you understand my problem :(

Comment: Ok, do you mean that you want to send to the php script all the values of `$row['Delivery_no']` and `$row['Delivery_no']` and `$row['Invoice_no']` and `$row['Bill_date']` and `$row['Bill_to_party']` and so on...  . But you are sending **only**  `$row['Delivery_no']` ?

Comment: Yes those are the columns, which has around 1000 rows. And I only want to download those rows selected on checkbox.

Comment: Hey.. I've updated with your code.. Please check it.. The output I'm getting is all the columns getting displayed on one single row inside textboxes.. how do i give a break to each row?

Comment: No, please don't change the original problem . I said that **if** you need these values(Bill_date, Invoice_no, Bill_to_party, ...etc ) to be sent to the server, then you have to put them inside `<input>` elements. but I think this is not what you want. **I think you want to send only the "Delivery_no" column of the rows you check on their check boxes, Right?**

Comment: I'm using the Delivery_no coloumn only to use it in the query on the php page to select the entire row...
Select * from $DB_TBLName WHERE Delivery_no = '$_REQUEST[Delivery_no]'  ...
Like this

Comment: perfect. and you are getting an error of undefined index on that line `$_REQUEST[Delivery_no]` ??

Comment: Yes sir........

Comment: can you please write that line `var_dump($_REQUEST);` right before the sql query line. and tell me what you get on the web page?

Comment: Something like this... 
array(2) {  
  ["check"]=>  
  array(1) {  
    [0]=>  
    string(10) "8153065366"  
  }  
  ["submit"]=>  
  string(6) "submit"  
}  
...... And also I'm getting the same undefined index error

Comment: 8153065366 is the Delivery_No i selected on the checkbox

Comment: Bingo. this  Delivery_No "8153065366 " comes to the php server inside the variable `$_REQUEST['check'][0]` . you don't have variable called `$_REQUEST[Delivery_no]` . In that case replace `$_REQUEST[Delivery_no]` with `$_REQUEST['check'][0]` and tell if you getting the result you want or not?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: This is what the query looks like...
$sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName WHERE Delivery_no = '$_REQUEST['check'][0]'" ;

Comment: ah ok , just put the variable inside braces to be like this `$sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName WHERE Delivery_no = '{$_REQUEST['check'][0]}'" ;`

Comment: This is what I'm getting bro..
http://2.1m.yt/A5rmdgh.png

Comment: you tried to output the response header , but you already outputted something on line `57` of your file. the headers must be first thing to output .. **what do you have on line `57` ?**

Comment: print(trim($schema_insert));

Comment: remove it or comment it

Comment: Thanks a lot man.. You're a life saver.. Now I've got another problem.. The record gets displayed perfectly on single checkbox selection.. but on multiple selection, only the first selection gets displayed..

Comment: you are welcome. off curse you are going to display only the first selected row , we did `$_REQUEST['check'][0]` which means the first `0` Delivery_no of the selected ones, it will even fail if you didn't checked on anything . you have to loop throw the checked rows and display them if you want. as you looped throw them in your code `foreach($_POST['check'] as $selected) `

Comment: hey bro.. I've updated the PHP code in the question.. kindly look into it and tell me how I can apply the loop here?

Answer (score 0):

To check a checkbox you need to add the "checked" attribute. So if your `$row['Delivery_no']` contains a boolean indicating whether or not the checkbox should be checked, you could try:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="check[]" <?php if( $row['Delivery_no']) echo "checked"; ?> />
```

Comment: How do you determine whether the checkbox should be checked or not? What values are you expecting?

Comment: The values of one single row from mysql has to be retrieved on checkbox selection and button click.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood your question then. So your problem is that of your six 'echo' statements, only one works?

Comment: Kinda..  the thing is that there a total 21 columns in the database. I've just displayed the important ones on the form.. but on button click the entire checked row selected on checkbox should be retrieved  with the 21 columns. I hope you understand my problem :(

Comment: Can you check if 'mysqli_num_fields($result)' returns the correct result?

Comment: I don't understand :/

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, you're iterating over the results with
for ($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_fields($result); $i++) {
    echo mysqli_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
}
so you should check if thats actually iterating over the entire row

Comment: Yes. That code is correct. I'm able to retrieve all the records on select * query.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to keep my code as much close to your code. but please note that using `mysql` functions is not recommended and removed from php 7 . also the code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

as I told you in the comments just loop throw the selected rows and do to them what you have done with the first row in the previous version of your code.

```
$finalOutput = ""; // <-- my edit
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['check'])) {
        // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
        $sep = "\t";
        foreach($_POST['check'] as $selected) {
            $sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName WHERE Delivery_no = '$selected' " ;
            $result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());
            for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
                //echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
            }
            //print("\n");
            $schema_insert = "";
            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
            {
                for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
                {
                    if(!isset($row[$j]))
                        $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
                    elseif ($row[$j] != "")
                        $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
                    else
                        $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
                }
                $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
                $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
                $schema_insert .= "\t";
                $schema_insert = trim($schema_insert);
                $schema_insert.= "\n";
            }
        }
        $finalOutput .= $schema_insert; // <-- my edit (edited)
    }
}


$file_ending = "xls";
header("Content-Type: application/xls");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
die($finalOutput);
```

Comment: Hey bro.. I'll try to edit the program according to what you've posted.. I'm still having some problems after downloading the excel..

Comment: @starscream ok , you had the Idea. try to adjust it to what you need. good luck.. By the way, this is not your code and you are maintaining it, right?

Comment: Yes.. the PHP code isn't mine.. and I'm getting another problem man.. The checkbox selection is now working for multiple values, but it seems that the checkbox selection has gone into a loop.. It is not stopping after the 21 columns, it keeps repeating.. How do I put a break?

Comment: all the loops in that code seems to be breakable . can you show me how did you edit the loops lines `for` statements, and `while` statement

Comment: I did't edit anything.. see I'm really new to programming.. and this is a part of the compulsory project we have to do this semester.. I know client side scripting but my logic building is weak.. so I don't understand how to edit your code according to mine..

Comment: I'm sorry but solving the problem this way will fail in most cases. you have to know what are you doing. regarding the loops, I don't know why this is happening, all the loops seems breakable for me. the ` foreach($_POST['check'] as $selected)` will not be initiated unless you check at least one checkbox in the client code.  the `for ($i= 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++)` and `while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))` and `for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)` loops will stop when all the rows in the `$result` object is looped. Is there any using scenario  makes the loop infinite?

Comment: Hey listen.. I've updated the php code.. kindly look into it..there seems to be a problem with the query

Comment: @starscream yes that sql statement has a problem, imploding the array without a [glue](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) will result for a long string containing all the checked numbers together. you need the `$checks`  variable to be something like this `"1,2,3,4,5"` NOT `"12345"` replace that line `$checks = implode(array_map('intval', $_REQUEST['check']));` with this **`$checks = implode(",",array_map('intval', $_REQUEST['check']));`**

Comment: Hey man.. nothing is getting displayed in the excel file except for the header.. i $echod the query.. this is what it looks like on excel for 2 selected checkbox.....
Select * from billing WHERE Delivery_no IN (2147483647,2147483647)Select * from billing WHERE Delivery_no IN (2147483647,2147483647)Select * from billing WHERE Delivery_no IN (2147483647,2147483647)Select * from billing WHERE Delivery_no IN (2147483647,2147483647)... I have no idea what those values in the bracket are.. it is not in the database

Comment: @starscream the sql in the question code should not produce that sql statement in your comment. I don't know how did that happened